# Using pdfbox in java to overlay text onto previously created pdf document

Tags: java, pdfbox

I already have several PDF documents that have been created. What I am attempting to do is by using PDFBox. I need to put text into several places on these created documents but I do NOT want to modify the text that is within those areas. For instance, there may be a a section as follows -

NAME: ______________________________

I will put text into that area, but I need the underline to remain the same length. I believe the best solution would be to just create a textbox or similar that goes above the area so the line remains the same length.

In other words, I do not want to edit the text inline so it will remain the same length. I have no code for this as I am just attempting to understand the pdfbox package. I have been looking for examples online, but most of them just show how to create a document and not how to update a previously document. How do I do this?

Comment: Assuming that you already know how to create a pdf and write text in it: You could simply create an extra content stream on an existing page and position your text at the place you wish, with new PDPageContentStream(doc, pdpage, false, false, true);

Comment: If you need more help, say so, and I'll create a tiny example tomorrow unless somebody else does it first.

Comment: get the pages with List<PDPage> pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

Comment: Let me fiddle with this over the next 24hrs, Tilman, and I'll let you know. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, for sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer and wanted to share.

In the pdfbox package there is a class called Overlay.

```
    PDDocument pdfDocument = new Overlay();
    PDDocument final = pdfDocument.overlay(PDDocument firstDoc, PDDocument otherDoc);
```

firstDoc will be overlaid onto otherDoc. Easy peasy. I just didn't know where to look.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need concrete example of use, you can refer to `OverlayPDF.java` in the [PDFBox reposity](https://apache.googlesource.com/pdfbox/+/trunk/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/OverlayPDF.java):

```
Overlay overlayer = new Overlay();
overlayer.setInputFile(inputFile);  //the file to be overlayed

PDDocument result = overlayer.overlay(overlayFile); //This will add overlays to a documents.
result.save(outputFilename);
result.close();
overlayer.close();  //close the input files AFTER saving the resulting file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to underline text in an existing pdf document.  You can try to use Java Itext, check this example and see if it helps.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/underline-strikethrough.html

Comment: No. More like this: http://imgur.com/oUExlNk I am just putting that text over the text that is already there.

Also, I cannot use iText. This is for a business project and management is apprehensive in purchasing iText. They see PDFBox and believe that I can do it in that package w/o needing to use another PDF option.