# Build PDF templates and populating then

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have the use case:

> Build a PDF template and populate with variables with Java API iText.

But, I only saw examples with Acro Forms and my PDF it's not a form, it is a contract, like:

> Rent to Own Contract
>        Whereas, ___________________ (hereafter Renter) desires to possess and have the use of certain property owned by
>   ____________________ (hereafter Owner) and described in Attachment A, (...)

I need to build this template and populate with an Object, where '____________' is the place of variables.

The document template it can be constructed with HTML or XML too!!

Any Ideas or help?

Comment: If you are willing to use pdfbox, please check out this thread as it is talking about doing exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189154/using-pdfbox-in-java-to-overlay-text-onto-previously-created-pdf-document

Comment: @blahfunk I fear that you didn't read the question. The answer you refer to works almost exactly the way AcroForms work. The OP wants the content of the template to reflow. As he indicates, using HTML or XML is a viable solution. In PDF all existing content is at fixed coordinates. The width of the placeholder needs to be known in advance and can't be variable. The only type of PDF where this is possible is XFA (which is actually XML wrapped in PDF). Using HTML in combination with iText's XML Worker might be a solution, but the question is too broad for a definitive answer.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I don't get anything for it. It was the solution that worked very beautifully for me in my pdf scenario. I evidently didn't understand this question correctly.